# How kill sql query which run more than 1 seconds with help TomCat jdbc pool?

Tags: java, sql, tomcat, jdbc, jdbc-pool

Which of the settings of `jdbc` pool may help me with killing sql query which runs more than 1 seconds?

When I say `tomcat jdbc pool` I mean Resource in `context.xml` in `/tomcat/conf/` directory.

Comment: removeAbandonedTimeout="1" does not help me

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the tomcat pool provides an out-of-the-box interceptor to do this for you. See...

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.QueryTimeoutInterceptor

You should be able to add one of these interceptors to your config

(Note: that document says *it is still up to the JDBC driver to enforce query timeouts.*)